# Screen is freezing when download app from iTunes

Tags: app-store-connect, ios11, testflight, xcode9.2

I am facing weird problem in one of my application.

When app is in development, everything is working fine. I have install app in device by various ways :

- Directly connect device and installed
- Create .ipa and connect device and install via `Devices and Simulators` by dragging
- Create .ipa and installed via `Diawi`

In all above case app working fine.

But when I am download from iTunes :

- Live app
- TestFlight App

It causes problem.

Now problem is :

- App has listing screen (e.g : User's list, Property list).
- Click on any cell, it will redirect to details screen.
- Now details screen has one button at bottom right corner
- Click on button, will open action sheet with some options
- Click on `Cancel`, screen becomes slight dark and freeze, unresponsive.

But it is only happen when download app from the `iTunes Connect`. This is only happen on this - single screen. All other working fine. Whole app is also working fine.

Please note that I am using :

- Default action sheet (`UIAlertController`) with type `UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet`
- Default `UITextView`
- Default `UIButton`
- Swift 3.*
- Xcode 9.2
- iOS 11.*

Please help me to solve this out. I can't get any clue. This is really strange issue.